# Java textField infinite loop

Tags: java, jtextfield, infinite-loop

Game class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {
public static void main(String args[]){

    //----------Sets up GUI----------

    GUI gameGUI = new GUI();
    gameGUI.setVisible(true);
    Player.setGUI(gameGUI);


    //----------Sets initial number of marbles, computer player and human player----------

    Random random = new Random();
    int initialNum;
    //loop makes sure initialNum of marbles is between 10 and 100
    do{                                 
        initialNum = random.nextInt(100);
    }while(initialNum < 10);
    //*****gameGUI.manageMarbles(initialNum, true);
    //end loop

    Pile pile = new Pile(initialNum);
    gameGUI.setPile(pile);

    int compChoice = random.nextInt(2) + 1; //number index (1 or 2) representing SIMPLE_COMPUTER or SMART_COMPUTER
    Player computer = new Player(Player.Type.values()[compChoice]);
    Player humanPlayer = new Player(Player.Type.HUMAN);


    //----------Game loop----------

    //Randomly determine first player
    Player currentPlayer;
    int playerIndex = random.nextInt(2); //will be used to determine next player in the loop
    if(playerIndex == 0){ currentPlayer = computer; }
    else { currentPlayer = humanPlayer; }

    //Loop
    while(pile.getNumMarbles() != 0){
        System.out.printf("%d marbles left.\n", pile.getNumMarbles());
        int removed = currentPlayer.playTurn(pile.getNumMarbles());
        pile.removeMarbles(removed);

        //Determine next player
        playerIndex = Math.abs(playerIndex - 1); //if playerIndex = 0, it becomes 1, and vice-versa
        if(playerIndex == 0){ currentPlayer = computer; }
        else { currentPlayer = humanPlayer; }

    }

    System.out.println(currentPlayer + " won");



}
}
```

Player class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Player {

    public enum Type{HUMAN, SIMPLE_COMPUTER, SMART_COMPUTER}
    private Type type;
    static private GUI gui;

    public Player(Player.Type type){
         this.type = type;
    }

    public Player.Type getType(){
         return type;
    }

    public int playTurn(int pileSize){
          Random random = new Random();
          if(type == Type.HUMAN){

              int marbles;
          do{
             marbles = gui.getMarblesToRemove();
          }while(marbles < 0);
              return marbles;

          }

          else if(type == Type.SIMPLE_COMPUTER){
           if(pileSize == 1){
               return 1;
               }
           else{
           int remove = random.nextInt(pileSize/2) + 1;
               if(remove == (pileSize/2) + 1){ remove -= 1; }
               return remove;
               }
          }

          else if(type == Type.SMART_COMPUTER){ 
               if(pileSize == 1){
               return 1;
            }
               else if(pileSize == 3 || pileSize == 7 || pileSize == 15 || pileSize== 31 || pileSize== 63 || pileSize <= 3){
              int remove = random.nextInt(pileSize/2) + 1;
              if(remove == (pileSize/2) + 1){ remove -= 1; }
              return remove;
            }
           else{
               for(int i=1; i<=pileSize/2; i++){
                   int size = pileSize - i;
               if(size == 3 || size == 7 || size == 15 || size == 31 || size == 63){
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;

   }


public String toString(){
    return ""+type;
}

public static void setGUI(GUI guii){
    gui = guii;
}


}
```

GUI class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

  private JPanel panel;
  private JButton removeButton; //button to remove marbles
  private JTextField marblesAmount; //amount of marbles to remove
  private static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 2;
  private JLabel marblesLabel;
  private JLabel errorLabel;
  private Pile pile;
  private int marblesToRemove;
  private ClickListener listener;
  static final private int WIDTH = 700, HEIGHT = 600;

  public GUI(){
    super.setTitle("test");
    super.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel = new JPanel();
    marblesLabel = new JLabel("How many marbles to remove?");
    errorLabel = new JLabel("");
    removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    listener = new ClickListener();
    removeButton.addActionListener(listener);
    marblesAmount = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    panel.add(removeButton);
    panel.add(marblesLabel);
    panel.add(marblesAmount);
    panel.add(errorLabel);
    super.add(panel);
    marblesToRemove = 0;
  }

  public void setPile(Pile pile){
    this.pile = pile;
  }



  private class ClickListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        marblesToRemove = Integer.parseInt(marblesAmount.getText());

    }
  }

  public int getMarblesToRemove(){
    return marblesToRemove;
  }


}
```

Pile Class:

public class Pile {

```
private int initialNum;
private int currentNum;

public Pile(int initialNum){
    setNumMarbles(initialNum);
    currentNum = initialNum;
}

public int getNumMarbles(){
    return currentNum;
}

public void removeMarbles(int numToRemove){
    currentNum = currentNum - numToRemove;
}

public void setNumMarbles(int amount){
    initialNum = amount;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Number of marbles: " + currentNum;
}

}
```

What I am trying to do is to get the  function playTurn(int pileSize)  in the Player class to return the variable marbles(inside the if(type == Type.HUMAN) block )   only when it is not zero. The variable `marblesToRemove` from the gui class is assigned to marbles, by calling the function `getMarblesToRemove()`.

`marblesToRemove` is initially set to `0` in the default constructor for the gui class, and that causes the functionplayTurn(int pileSize) to go in an infinite loop. But `marblesToRemove` is changed to another value that is input in a `JTextField` (`marblesAmount`) when a a button(`removeButton`) is pressed. But the the do while loop will still be an infinite loop and the function will return nothing, why? Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `getMarblesToRemove()` method ?

Comment: Sounds like you either blocking the EDT or starving the process's threads.  In what context is `playTurn` executed?

Comment: getMarblesToRemove() is on the bottom of the second block of code in the gui class

Comment: MadProgrammer Sorry I dont know what EDT is. Play turn is executed inside a while loop...I'd better paste the full code I think...its quite big though x(

Comment: i couldn't understand why do you call getMarblesToRemove method in a while loop.

Comment: Is `playTurn(int pileSize)` running in separate thread?

Comment: The code, variable that calls playTurn  to get its return value will need an integer that is not zero and that is given in the JTextField marblesAmount, this value is assigned to the marblesToRemove variable after a button is clicked, thats why I created an ActionListener . So I thought the best way would be to keep getting the value of marblesToRemove by using getMarblesToRemove() method inside a while loop until it is different than zero, which would be after someone input an integer different than zero in the JTextField and clicked the button..Does it make sense? x(

Comment: playTurn(int pileSize) is inside a different class, the Player class, which I did not include here.

Comment: EDT = Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Or in short how you calling this method. ? Show the code where you are calling it.

Comment: I will add the whole code here..which has four classes: Game, Pile, GUI and Player.

Comment: This is a pain in the ass to edit, I hope it is readable..
It seems like the solution would be complicated considering my knowledge in Java...I'm just learning it, this is the first project I do with a GUI =/

Comment: There is little change in the code that you have posted for `playTurn(int pileSize)` in edited version and earlier version of question. Earlier you had `while(marbles == 0);` whereas in edited version you had `while(marbles < 0);`

Comment: and you still do not have any synchronization on the marbles .... have you lost them yet?

Comment: Vishal K oh yes, I forgot to edit that..it is because I set the initial value of MarblesToRemove to -1 ...but it doesnt really change much I think.

rolfl - what do you mean by  synchronization ?

Comment: @LucasMezalira ... your program is running in multiple threads. You are not using good multi-thraead code. At the moment it *maY* appear to be working, but it will fail again. The previous suggestion to us 'volatile marblesToRemove' will allow the program to be accurate, but it is not going to help with the other problem which is the tight loop on the marblesToRemove variable. To fix that you need to use synchronization and notification. Bottom line: you have a fair idea of how it should behave, you encountered a bug, and you have the wrong 'fixes' (which fix the symptom, not the problem)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of at least two issues that I can see. The first is that you are modifying the variable in one thread, and reading it in the other. This should be done using either synchronization, or some other locking mechanism (Lock or AtomicInteger, etc.).

The second issue is that your reading-thread should *not* be doing a 'tight' loop. This is bad practices that sends one CPU to 100% usage. It should be done using some form of notification. Again, synchronization comes to mind.

Until you fix these two issues, you will always have unreliable results.

For what it's worth, in your particular case, if I were to make an educated guess, I would guess that there are two important copies of the marblesAmount (and there are alsways multiple copies). There's the copy thati's in the L1 and registers of one CPU that's doing a tight loop waiting for that register to change, and the other is in another core on your CPU setting it to a new value. Unless you use some synchronization, or somethin from the java.util.concurrent.* library you ave no way to tell one copy of the variable to refresh the other.

Comment: Also my guess. Just to point this fact out another time: Try to avoid to run a loop like this. If you need to do something like this, you should better rethink if another solution to your problem would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work finally. I just added a line of code "System.out.print("");" in the do-while loop in the Player class.

So now it looks like

```
 do{
         marbles = gui.getMarblesToRemove();
         System.out.print("");
      }while(marbles < 0);
```

I have no idea why that works, but it does lol. Now the function actually returns the value that I set in the JTextField if it is not zero.

Comment: Your code was still working fine without using `System.out.print("");`. The only change that made it work is `while(marbles < 0)` in your case. But I checked your code for `while(marbles == 0)` also..It worked fine at my end. I would suggest you to declare `marblesToRemove` as `private volatile int marblesToRemove;` . `Votalite` keyword will ensure that the updated value of `marblesToRemove` will be seen by EDT and `playTurn` method.